# Generate a PDF in Landscape Format From Doxygen

Tags: latex, doxygen

I am using doxygen to generate .chm and .pdf files.

In order to generate a PDF, I made some changes to my .dox configuration file:

```
GENERATE_LATEX = YES
COMPACT_LATEX = YES
GENERATE_DOCBOOK = YES
PERLMOD_LATEX = YES
```

Now, when I run doxygen on the .dox file, it generates a latex folder which contains some .tex files and make.bat file.

Before I run the make.bat file, I need to manually modify one of the .tex files to make the PDF that is generated from running make.bat appear in a landscape page orientation.

Is there a way to modify the .dox configuration to automatically generate the latex .tex file to include the change for enabling a landscape orientation?

Comment: Which settings are you changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen has no direct possibility to change the page orientation in the `Doxyfile`. The mechanisms for this are currently:

- editing the `refman.tex`
- creating a custom latex header `doxygen -w latex headerFile footerFile styleSheetFile` edit the `headerfile` and specify this file in setting `LATEX_HEADER` in the Doxyfile (NOTE the content of this file can change with a new release).